# Get all available properties of a class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a the following class

```
class A {
  id: number
  propertyA: string

  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id
  }
}

let a = new A(3)

console.log(SomeFunction(a))
// expected output = ['id', 'propertyA']
```

Basically when I created an instance of A, I did not set the value for propertyA. When `SomeFunction(a)` is  called then it should return all the properties class A can have, which includes `propertyA` even though it has not been set.

`Object.getPropertyNames(a)` returns only `['id']`

What should be the code of SomeFunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you set a value for the property, it won't exist on the object. There's no metadata available at runtime that says "This property is declared but has never been assigned to."

You'll need to pick a default value for `propertyA` and set it (perhaps in an initializer on the declaration) if you want to ensure that every instance of `A` has that property.

For instance, if you're not using strict null checks, you might do this:

```
class A {
  id: number
  propertyA: string = undefined

  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id
  }
}
```

That means that `new A(42).propertyA` will continue to provide the value `undefined` (as it does with your existing `A` class), but the property will actually exist and so `SomeFunction` can find it.

Live Copy:

```js
class A {
  id /* : number*/
  propertyA /*: string*/ = undefined

  constructor(id/*: number*/) {
    this.id = id
  }
}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new A(42)));
```

If you're using strict null checks, you'll need to initialize it to a string.

Comment: Aah... I suspected so. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

As long as the value of the property is not set, it won't exist in the class instance.

Here, we can enumerate both `id` and `propertyA` but only when they are set:

```js
function showProps(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj);
}

class A {
  constructor(id, propA) {
    this.id = id;
    if (propA)
      this.propertyA = 0;
  }
}

const a = new A(3);
const b = new A(3, 1);

console.log(showProps(a));
console.log(showProps(b));
```

Comment: *"...once it is compiled to JavaScript, it disappears."* That depends on what version of JavaScript you have tsc set to target, as [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) is at an advanced stage (public fields are enabled by default on Chrome's V8, for instance) and will almost certainly land in the coming months and so be in the 2020 spec.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, thanks a lot for the precision, I will update my answer.